# Powershell Expired accounts

Tags: powershell

i am currently new to Powershell and i am in the process of writing a short script to output a list of users who accounts have expired longer than 30 days i have attempting to use Get-Date).adddays(-12) but i keep receiving invalid parameters when attempting this.

any pointers would be greatly appreciated and i have included the below sample of code i am attempting to get working.

```
$result = 
foreach($OU in $OUS){
    Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -Filter 'enabled -eq $false' -Properties AccountExpirationDate  | Select sAMAccountName, distinguishedName, AccountExpirationDate
}
$result | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\leavers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What do you mean with invalid parameters? Is that the error message? If so, please add the full error message to your question. Did you try to run your `Get-ADUser` line in an isolated run?

Comment: The `AccountExpirationDate` property can be easily compared to a date set in the past with `-lt` in your case. This can also be added in the `-Filter` parameter. Is the problem simply because you are forgetting an opening bracket like in your description?

Comment: Try `[datetime]::now - [timespan]::FromDays(12)`